# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - Can't solve a Path problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this problem, I'm trying to run the script to download Springers free books [https://towardsdatascience.com/springer-has-released-65-machine-learning-and-data-books-for-free-961f8181f189], but many things start to go wrong.
I solved some of the problems but now I'm stuck.

```
    C:\Windows\system32>python C:\Users\loren\Desktop\springer_free_books-master\main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\loren\Desktop\springer_free_books-master\main.py", line 42, in <module>
    books.to_excel(table_path)
  File "C:\Users\loren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2175, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "C:\Users\loren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 738, in write
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\loren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 43, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "C:\Users\loren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 392, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\loren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 291, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\loren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'downloads\\table_v4.xlsx'
```

This is part of the code, were table_path is introduced.

```
table_url = 'https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/17858272/data/v4'

table = 'table_' + table_url.split('/')[-1] + '.xlsx'
table_path = os.path.join(folder, table)
if not os.path.exists(table_path):
    books = pd.read_excel(table_url)
    # Save table
    books.to_excel(table_path)
else:
    books = pd.read_excel(table_path, index_col=0, header=0)
```

Comment: Does the downloads directory exist?  And if so, does the python process have write permissions there?
you're running the Python script from `c:\windows\system32`.  That will cause trouble when you need to write a file.  Try changing to your home directory (where `Downloads` probably exists) before running the script.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

EDIT*
`C:\Users\loren>python C:\Users\loren\Desktop\springer_free_books-master\main.py
[...]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Download\\table_v4.xlsx'`
Nope, same error.

Comment: try doing `mkdir Download` from your command prompt, and re-run.  (Note `Download` vs. `Downloads`).  Or change the `folder` variable so that it uses `Downloads` for the file path.

Comment: Yes, I've been inattentive, the names were different and I've created the "downloads" folder as named on code script. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the destination directory before calling `.to_excel()` to ensure a valid writable directory exists.  Make sure the `os` module is imported:

```
import os      # add to your imports
```

and replace

```
    books.to_excel(table_path)
```

with

```
    os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)
    books.to_excel(table_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem creating another directory that actually had same name as the code one, I've been inattentive.